# Multiple roles to single user

Tags: sql, database, relational-database

I want to design a schema for my SQL database in which a user can have multiple roles like admin,tester, developer and they will have the accessibility to the module(test,develop,performance) as per their role.
I tried to design three tables first of users in which user will have id and its role id,second one of role ,and the third will be of module which will have the foreign key of user and role in which it will assign the permission to that role.

But it fails when a user will have multiple roles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a basic many-to-many relationship to me - so you need three tables:
two entity tables and one conjunction table.
In your case there should be a user table, a role table, and userToRole table.
The module / role is usually also a many to many relationship - since many roles might be connected to a single module, and many modules might be connected to a single role.

A basic implementation might look like this :

```
tblUser
(
    User_id int primary key,
    -- Other user related columns
)

tblRole
{
    Role_Id int primary key,
    -- Other role related columns
}

tblUserToRole
{
    URT_User int Foreign key to tblUser,
    URT_Role int Foreign key to tblRole,
    Primary key (URT_User, URT_Role)
}
```

Comment: but if a user will have multiple roles will it not have multiple userToRole ids

Comment: If a user will have multiple rows it will have multiple records in the UserToRole table, each with a different role id. That's how many to many relationships work in relational databases.